# grouping objects according to some fields

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a List of an Object, with the following characteristics:

```
Class myObject{
  String gender;
  String state;
  int quantity;
  int Salary;
}

List<myObject> myList=new ArrayList<Object>;
```

As input of the List, i have the following:

[image]

and as Output, i want to keep only one occurrence of the object with the same gender and the same state, in the same time sum the quantity and the salsary correspanding, like the following:

[image]

my question is how can i loop through myList, find objects with the same gender and the same state,keep only one occurence of them, and sum the quantity and the salary correspanding ??

in other words, for the first and second line (same gender, same state), keep only one line and sum the correspanding quantity and salary

Comment: This question is too broad; in the sense of: you are not telling us what your exact coding problem is. It very much sounds like you want us to **teach** how to do all those things; instead of you **learning** yourself how to do it.

Comment: @Jägermeister I disagree with your comment. The question is clear and I can read what exactly he needs.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Collection<MyObject> aggregate(List<MyObject> objects) {
    Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
    for (MyObject current : objects) {
       String key = String.format("%s:%s", current.gender, current.state);
       MyObject aggregated = map.get(key);
       if (aggregated == null) {
           aggregated = new MyObject();
           aggregated.gender = current.gender;
           aggregated.state = current.state;
           map.put(key, aggregated);
       }
       aggregated.quantity += current.quantity;
       aggregated.salary += current.salary;
    }
    return map.values();
}
```

Comment: Oh cool. I have to keep in mind that sometimes Stackoverflow really works as "please do all the work for me and code the solution to my problem for me".

Comment: Interestingly enough, the OP is now asking a second question; as he took your code; but is still lacking the essential skills to adapt it further to his needs. How surprising.

Comment: lol... you're right... it seems I [gave a man a fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent with Java 8:

```
private static Collection<myObject> aggregate(List<myObject> objects) {
        return objects.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(myObject::genderAndState, reducing(new myObject(), myObject::merge)))
                .values();
    }

private static myObject merge(myObject o1, myObject o2) {
    myObject tmp = new myObject();
    tmp.gender = o2.gender;
    tmp.state =  o2.state;
    tmp.quantity= o1.quantity + o2.quantity;
    tmp.salary = o1.salary + o2.salary;
    return tmp;
}

private static String genderAndState(myObject o) {
    return o.gender.concat(o.state);
}
```

Comment: @hamzaspecter Ok no problem. However, I let my answer for the ones who are on Java 8.